# Overriding methods for defining custom model field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-model-field

I have been trying to define custom django model field in python. I referred the django docs at following location https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-model-fields/. However, I am confused over the following methods(which I have divided into groups as per my understanding) :-

Group 1  (Methods in this group are inter-related as per docs)

1. `__init__`()
2. deconstruct()

Group 2

1. db_type()
2. rel_db_type()
3. get_internal_type()

Group 3

1. from_db_value()
2. to_python()
3. get_prep_value()
4. get_db_prep_value()
5. get_db_prep_save()
6. value_from_object()
7. value_to_string()

Group 4

1. formfield

I am having following questions :-

1. When `deconstruct()` is used ? Docs says that, it's useful during migration, but it's not clearly explained. Moreover, when is it called ?
2. Difference between `db_type()` and `get_internal_type()`
3. Difference between `get_prep_value()` and `get_db_prep_value()`
4. Difference between `value_from_object()` and `value_to_string()`. `value_from_object()` is not given in docs.
5. Both `from_db_value()`, `value_to_string()` and `to_python()` gives python object from string. Then, why these different methods are exists ?

I know, I have asked a bit lengthy question. But couldn't find any other way to better ask this question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

I'll try to answer them:

**Q:** When `deconstruct()` is used ?

**A:** This method is being used when you have instance of your `Field` to re-create it based on arguments you just passed in `__init__`.
As they mentioned in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction), if you are setting `max_length` arg to a static value in your `__init__` method; you do not need it for your instances. So you can delete it in your `deconstruct()` method. With this, `max_length` won't show up in your instance while you are using it in your models. You can think `deconstruct` as a last clean-up and control place before use your field in model.

---

**Q:** Difference between `db_type()` and `get_internal_type()`

**A:** They are both related, but belong to different levels.

If your custom field's data type is depends on which DB you are using, *`db_type()`* is the place you can do your controls. Again, like they mentioned in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-model-fields/#custom-database-types), if your field is a kind of date/time value, you should / may check if current database is `PostgreSQL` or `MySQL` in this method. Because while date/time values called as `timestamp` in `PostgreSQL`, it is called `datetime` in `MySQL`.

`get_internal_type` method is kind of higher level version of `db_type()`. Let's go over date/time value example: If you don't want to check and control each data types belongs to different databases, you can inherit your custom field's data type from `built-in` Django fields. Instead of checking if it should be `datetime` or `timestamp`; you can return simply `DateField` in your `get_internal_type` method. As they mentioned in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-model-fields/#emulating-built-in-field-types), If you've created `db_type` method already, in most cases, you do not need `get_internal_type` method.

---

**Q:** Difference between `get_prep_value()` and `get_db_prep_value()`

**A:** These guys also share `almost` same logic between `db_type()` and `get_internal_type()`. First of all, both these methods stands for converting db values to `python objects`. But, like in `db_type` method, `get_db_prep_value()` stands for `backend` specific field types.

---

**Q:** Difference between `value_from_object()` and `value_to_string()`. `value_from_object()` is not given in docs

**A:** From the docs:

> To customize how the values are serialized by a serializer, you can
>   override `value_to_string()`. Using `value_from_object()` is the best way
>   to get the field’s value prior to serialization.

So, Actually we don't need `value_from_object` as documented. This method is used to get field's raw value before serialization. Get the value with this method, and customize how it should be serialized in `value_to_string` method. They even put an example code in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-field-data-for-serialization)

---

**Q:** Both `from_db_value()`, `value_to_string()` and `to_python()` gives python object from string. Then, why these different methods are exists ?

**A:** While `to_python()` converts field value to a valid python object, `value_to_string()` converts field values to string with your custom serialization. They stands for different jobs.

And `from_db_value` converts the value returned by database to python object. Never heard of it actually. But check [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.from_db_value) from docs:

> This method is not used for most built-in fields as the database
>   backend already returns the correct Python type, or the backend itself
>   does the conversion.

Comment: Still the first answer is not clear, wrt to when deconstruct() is called. Moreover get_prep_value() and get_db_prep_value() is also misleading, as docs says that they are used to convert values from python types to dbcolumn type.

Comment: As it has already been mentioned, this answer is mislieading. `get_prep_value` and `get_db_prep_value` convert from Python to database value, not the other way around.